# CSS - Select table with thead that has specifc class

Tags: html, css, html-table

i have a table as follows

```
<table class="bordered">
<thead class="info">
<tr>
<th>one</th>
<th>two</th>
<th>three</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

i want to apply borders to  to table whose thead class is info

css currently contains

```
.bordered td{
border: 1px solid #0060a0  !important;
}
```

Comment: So you basicly want to do a child > parent which is not possible in css. you have to use js/jquery

Comment: As pointed out by @user5014677 this is pretty much impossible with pure CSS. Is editing the html possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a sibling selector

```
.bordered thead.info + tbody td
```

This selector targets all `td` elements within a `tbody` element which is an adjacent sibling to a `thead.info` element within a `.bordered` table. That sounds confusing, so here's a demo:

```css
.bordered thead.info + tbody td  {
  border: 1px solid #0060a0;
}
```

```html
<table class="bordered">
  <thead class="info">
    <tr>
      <th>one</th>
      <th>two</th>
      <th>three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A slightly more robust solution, which would be required if the table contained a `tfoot` element would be to use the more general sibling selector.

```css
.bordered thead.info ~ tbody td  {
  border: 1px solid #0060a0;
}
```

```html
<table class="bordered">
  <thead class="info">
    <tr>
      <th>one</th>
      <th>two</th>
      <th>three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Footer</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: no i want to add style to <td> that are <tbody>, but to tables that have a thead with class info only and not all tables

Comment: Read what he asked. He want to style the table if the thead is info.

Comment: @JenuRudan I have updated the solution. In the future, please provide a full working example to reduce confusion.